# Firestore Geohash Query with Live Updating Results in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build an iOS app in SwiftUI where users can find a "Post" near to their current location. I have a sub collection called Posts with a geohash. Somewhat annoyingly this library by google has been archived https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc for no reason. Instead I had to use this library https://github.com/emilioschepis/swift-geohash.

I find all the neighboring geohashes around the current user and then run a query against firstore for each geohash starting with geohash and ending with geohash + '~'.
Here is the function I wrote:

```
// import https://github.com/emilioschepis/swift-geohash

class FirestorePosts: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var items = [FirestorePost]() // Reference to our Model
      
    func geoPointQuery(tag:String){
        do {
            let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("tags")
            let docRef = db.document(tag).collection("posts")
            // users current location is "gcpu"
            let neighbors = try Geohash.neighbors(of: "gcpu", includingCenter: true)
            let queries = neighbors.map { bound -> Query in
                let end = "\(bound)~"
                return docRef
                    .order(by: "geohash")
                    .start(at: [bound])
                    .end(at: [end])
            }
            
            func getDocumentsCompletion(snapshot: QuerySnapshot?, error: Error?) -> () {
                guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                    print("Unable to fetch snapshot data. \(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }

                self.items += documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> FirestorePost? in
                    return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: FirestorePost.self)
                }
            }

            for query in queries {
                print("ran geo query")
                query.getDocuments(completion: getDocumentsCompletion)
            }
        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

So far the query works and returns items as expected. However, the results are not updated in realtime when there is a change in Firestore.

1. How could I make this query update results in realtime? I tried adding `query.addSnapshotListener` instead but it doesn't like "completion:" parameter
2. How can I ensure that all the queries are finished before returning the results

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `query.getDocuments`, which [gets data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data). If you want to also get updates to that data, you should use `addSnapshotListener` which [listens for updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) after getting the initial docs.

To ensure all queries are finished, you could keep a simple counter that you increase each time your `addSnapshotListener` callback is invoked. When the counter is equal to the number of queries, all of them have gotten a response from the server. That's exactly what the `geofire-*` libraries for Realtime Database do for their `onReady` event.

Comment: Thanks frank, would i still need to use the counter since I'm += appending the documents to self.items? not sure if im overwriting state there?

Comment: "How can I ensure that all the queries are finished before returning the results" Nothing about that is related to the number of documents (i.e. there may be queries without documents), so a counter is the simplest way to check if all queries have completed.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored to this and it seems to work and updates in realtime. I didn't need to use a counter since Im appending the documents to `self.items` (not sure if thats correct though).

```
...
for query in queries {
    query.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents")
            return
        }
        
        self.items += documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> FirestorePost? in
            return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: FirestorePost.self)
        }
    }
}
```